# Move logo to the left a few px

Tags: html, css

I recently had a problem where my logo would be would be cut off when I tried minimising my browser. That was easily solved by taking away margin-left{negative-value;} Now, my logo is positioned where I would like to move it to the left a few px but obviously don't want to use the above property and value. I tried margin-right which didn't seem to work. I also want to stay way from positioning and just focus on using normal flow. In the picture below you can see the background image of the home navigation link is overlapping with the logo. I just want to move it over to the left a bit Any help appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/w95n3x0L/2/

```
<div id="header">
<p id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer">
</p>
</div>

#logo img {
width: 320px;
margin-top: -60px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show this in an HTML/CSS snippet or on a JSFiddle?

Comment: my logo wouldn't show up since it's on my computer.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Could you provide images?

Comment: I just added a pic. the background image of the home navigation link is overlapping with the logo. I just want to move it over to the left a bit but without using a negative value or positioning.

Comment: ov ov then edit the image itself !? this question is getting more and more abroad! please give the all necessary parts to make it smaller problem. People are trying to guess what your problem really is.

Comment: okay. I made a jsfiddle. All i want is to move the logo to the left a few px. so the background image of my home navigation isn't overlapping. I just want to scoot it over leaving everything else in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just want to move it over to the left a bit but without using a
>   negative value or positioning.

You can't move it to the left without using a negative value as the image has no **computed left margin**. Just use such `margin-left: -50px;` if you want to move it over to the left:

```
#logo > img {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

> All i want is to move the logo to the left a few px. so the background
>   image of my home navigation isn't overlapping.

If you want to get rid of a link-overlapping image, then you can set the `z-index` of your `#nav-bar` higher than the `z-index` of your header such like this:

```
#nav-bar {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This way, the `#logo` will overlap the `#nav-bar` no more.

Also please change `<p id="logo">...</p>` to `<div id="logo">...</div>` as its content doesn't have a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

To move the logo some pixels to the left, you should add `position: relative` to the `#header` and position the `logo` absolute like this:

(Please remove the `p` tag from your logo section like this):

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header{
    position: relative;
}
#logo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 60px;
    left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always crop source image if that's not a problem. But if you do not want to do this you can set image as background and move it a little bit like this:

```
<p id="logo"></p>
```

And apply this CSS:

```
p#logo {
    height: 154px;
    width: 320px;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/UwpTOvm.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: -25px; /*move it to the left*/
    background-size: 100%;
}
```